# SQLite database size getting increase

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to run "Vacuum" command for SqLite database

```
     String sql = "VACUUM;" ;
    if(!IsSyncTriggered()){
        databaseInstance.execSQL(sql);
        databaseInstance.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
```

My complete class

```
        public class AppServiceDBClean extends WakefulIntentService {   
int FIVE_MINUTES = 5*60*1000;
public AppServiceDBClean() {
    super("AppService");     
}       

@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App services", 50000).show();

    try {
        doCleanUPDB();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("AppService", "Exception appending to log file", e);
    }  
}
public boolean IsSyncTriggered() {

    boolean isActive = false;
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext());
    Account[] ac = am.getAccountsByType(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    if (ac.length > 0) {
        isActive = ContentResolver.isSyncActive(ac[0], Constants.AUTHORITY);
    }
    return isActive;
}
public void doCleanUPDB(){

    /**
     * Create some basic instance of database interaction
     */
    DaoSession daoSessionUni = TAndroidApplicationContext.getInstance().getDaoSession();
    TAndroidApplicationContext tAndroidApplicationContext = TAndroidApplicationContext.getInstance();
    TDatabaseLibrary tDB = TDatabaseLibrary.getInstance(tAndroidApplicationContext.getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabaseWrapper databaseInstance = tDB.getDatabase();
    String sql = "VACUUM;" ;
    if(!IsSyncTriggered()){
        databaseInstance.execSQL(sql);
        databaseInstance.setTransactionSuccessful();
        //databaseInstance.endTransaction();
    }else{
        /**
         * If the sync is in progress
         * wait for 10 minutes and try again
         * */
        try {
            Thread.sleep(FIVE_MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d("DataCleaningService","SleepException ",e);
            e.printStackTrace();     

        }
    }




}
```

}

IsSyncTriggered() is User-define method. I am trying to achieve this by a services which will run once in every 24 hour.But my database size is not decreasing . It remain  goes increasing even some rows form table deleted. what i missed here Please help me . Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Can I have ur complete class ?

Comment: @Mann.. Thanks for your response . I update my question. Please have a look ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable `auto_vacuum` and upgrade the bbdd. If you sync your data with a webservice or something like that you shouldn't have any problem. 
If you can't lose the data then try this:

Remove the last ";" from the command. I know it might sound stupid but all the info I´ve recovered about vacuum on sqlite appears without it, so maybe isn't even firing the command.

```
if(!IsSyncTriggered()){
    databaseInstance.execSQL("VACUUM");
    databaseInstance.setTransactionSuccessful();
    //databaseInstance.endTransaction();
}else{
```

There´s also a bug report for vacuum command on previous android versions such 2.3. If you're having this issue on that version or previous ones you should search more about that bug.

[Bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2959)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response . Ok i am going enable PRAGMA auto_vacuum = FULL;........Is i am correct?

Comment: Yeps, It is. Take a look here http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum

Comment: But i have one confusion that i have to enable this at my Android Service or in that class where database created. ?

Comment: This should be added when you create your database, as it can't be done after the tables are created. Then after every commit it will execute the vacuum command.

Comment: "Then after every commit it will execute the vacuum command."..means through service  in particular interval of time.e.g Once in 24 hour or once in Week.

Comment: Only if the service commits. Imagine that your service reads info from your ws but this gives no changes, then it doesn't update the database then there´s no commit so no vacuum gets executed. You are automating the vacuum command relaying on your logic layer of database interaction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57268/discussion-between-axierjhtjz-and-blue-green).

Comment: How to Call or Run PRAGMA auto_vacuum = FULL in android code?